# "New edge/face from vertices" not joining selected vertices

Tags: vertices, edges, svg

I have a simple vector spaceship design for a retro "Elite" style game.  It was originally an SVG.  So far I have:

1. Converted from curves to mesh
2. Joined to a single mesh
3. Duplicated the meshes to give two parallel meshes one above the other

Now I'm trying to join the two meshes to give a "solid" object.  I've done this with a previous imported SVG by following the same workflow and selecting each vertex then using "F" (new edge/face from vertices).  However, with this example, the new edge is created at the "wrong end" of the edge, not between the vertices I selected.  I think this is something to do with metadata about the edges that has been retained from the SVG after importing, but I can't work out how to fix it and make the vertices behave how I want.

Imported, converted joined SVG:

[image]

Duplicated with a few adjustments:
[image]

What I want (edge indicated by arrow):
[image]

What I get after hitting 'F' (wrong vertices are joinined)
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you duplicate in edit or on object mode?

It should work properly if both planes belong to one object.

Comment: I think Object.  Which is correct?  I can redo the duplication.

I tried it in Edit mode, and it now appears to be working correctly.  I didn't know duplication was different in either mode.  I'll mark you as the answer.